# AngularJS ng-repeat for input array

Tags: angularjs, arrays, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have empty model with cars:

```
$scope.registration.cars = {
    1: {
        capacity: '',
        count: '',
        license: ''
    },
    2: {
        capacity: '',
        count: '',
        license: ''
    }
};
```

Then I use ng-repeat to generate cars form:

```
<div class="row row_vehicles" ng-repeat="(key, value) in registration.cars">
    <input type="number" name="registration_car_capacity[{{key}}]" ng-model="registration.car[{{key}}].capacity" />
    <input type="number" name="registration_car_count[{{key}}]" ng-model="registration.car[{{key}}].count" required />
    <input type="text" name="registration_car_license[{{key}}]" ng-model="registration.car[1].license" ng-minlength="7" required />
</div>
```

But this is not working. How can I insert KEY into ng-model array?

Comment: Remove `{{}}` on the `name` and `nd-model` attributes like `ng-model="registration.car[key].capacity"`

Comment: @general666 you should consider who answered first while upvoting and answering . :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use interpolation operator (`{{..}}`) inside angular scope.(anything like `ng-*`), In your case `ng-model`

```
<div class="row row_vehicles" ng-repeat="(key, value) in registration.cars">
    <input type="number" name="registration_car_capacity[key]" ng-model="registration.car[key].capacity" />
    <input type="number" name="registration_car_count[key]" ng-model="registration.car[key].count" required />
    <input type="text" name="registration_car_license[key]" ng-model="registration.car[key].license" ng-minlength="7" required />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanak you for solution ;)

Answer (score 2):

You just have to remove interpolation {{}} enclosing the key. You can't use this with angular directives.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div class="row row_vehicles" ng-repeat="(key, value) in registration.cars">
        <input type="number" name="registration_car_capacity[key]"
        ng-model="registration.cars[key].capacity"
        />
        <input type="number" name="registration_car_count[key]"
        ng-model="registration.cars[key].count"
        required />
        <input type="text" name="registration_car_license[key]"
        ng-model="registration.cars[key].license"
        ng-minlength="7" required /> 
    </div>
</div>
```

**Working Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/12094/